# Checking for even and odd values in a loop with Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I do not understand why the following lisp program displays 15 lines of output as opposed to 10:

```
(defparameter x 1)
(dotimes (x 10)
  (if (oddp x)
    (format t "x is odd~%"))
    (format t "x is even~%"))
```

I am using CLISP 2.49 on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: What editor are you using ? It seems you lack good indentation. Here some ideas: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/editor-support.html

Comment: Note that you do not need `defparameter` here and it will almost certainly be harmful: `(dotimes (i ...) ...)` binds `i` itself (and is allowed to rebind it for each iteration in fact).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Current:

```
(if (oddp x)
    (format t "x is odd~%"))    ; <- extra parenthesis
    (format t "x is even~%"))
```

Wanted:

```
(if (oddp x)
    (format t "x is odd~%")
    (format t "x is even~%"))
```

You are escaping the if form before the else statement so the else statement gets always printed while the if statement gets printed 5 times.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the accepted answer, note that with an auto-indenting editor (e.g. with Emacs) those kinds of mistakes can be spotted easily. Your code auto-indents as follows:

```
(dotimes (x 10)
  (if (oddp x)
      (format t "x is odd~%"))
  (format t "x is even~%"))
```

The `if` and second `format` expressions are aligned vertically (they are siblings in the tree rooted at `dotimes`) whereas you want the second `format` to happen only when the test fails, at the same depth as the first one.

#### Remark

You can also factor some code:

```
(format t 
        (if (oddp x) 
          "x is odd~%" 
          "x is even~%"))
```

Or even:

```
(format t
        "x is ~:[even~;odd~]~%" 
        (oddp x))
```

The above relies on [conditional formatting](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cgb.htm).